# vsftp: don't allow ftp user to move up in a directory tree

Tags: permissions, users, vsftpd

I am using vsftp on Ubuntu 14.04 and have create a user using this command:

```
sudo adduser ftpuser --home /var/www/wp-content/uploads
```

The user has permission to see `/var/www/wp-content/uploads`
but this user is also able to move up in the directory structure, so they can see content in `/var/www` and also in `/var` and `/`

The user can't edit these as they are not the owner of these files, which is good, but is there any way to stop the user from changing directory?

Answer (score 5):

According to [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/94673), you need to edit `/etc/vsftpd.conf` and ensure the following line is there:

```
chroot_local_user=YES
```

Comment: thanks @chai-t-rex , i tried un-commenting chroot_local_user=YES but user can still move up in directories. so currently when user connects ftp he sees this directory path in ftp     '/var/www/wp-content/uploads'    but the path should be only  this     '/'.